# Configuring React Routes, Django URLs using Webpack

Tags: django, reactjs, webpack, django-rest-framework

Teaching myself how to use a React frontend with a Django server and I'm having difficulty getting the React routes to work properly. Whenever I reload the page it thinks I'm making a GET request to the server. Refreshing at localhost:8000 works fine, but anything other than an API route errors out.

Pretty sure the issue is in one of my urls.py files.

```
quiz_app/urls.py

urlpatterns = [
  path('', include('quizzes.urls')),
  path('', include('frontend.urls'))
]
```

```
frontend/urls.py

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index )
]
```

```
quizzes/urls.py

urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path(r'^nested_admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
  re_path('api/quizzes/', views.QuizList.as_view()),
  re_path('api/quizzes/<str:name>/', views.SingleQuiz.as_view()),
  re_path('api/questions/', views.QuestionList.as_view()),
  re_path('api/answers/', views.AnswerList.as_view())
]
```

For good measure:

```
frontend/views.py

def index(request):
  return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')
```

```
frontend/src/App.js

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Grid>
            <Header />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Quizzes} />
            <Route exact path="/:name" component={Quiz} />
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
};
```

To reiterate, the issue is that the `"/:name"` routes in App.js are attempting to make "GET" requests to the Django server and erroring out because there's nothing to handle them rather than defaulting to a React route. Let me know what I'm doing wrong here. I've fixed this problem when using React with other server frameworks, but I'm new to Python/Django so not sure where to go from here.

Comment: what library define that Router Component? usually in the frontend framework like (angular, react, vue ) the routers only handle te calls in (the client side) and draw the correct component for each route so you need a component that works like a service, and there make calls to the backend api.

Comment: I'm using react-router-dom. Sorry if I misphrased my question, but that is what I'm doing. Server calls are handled by different components, the problem being that it's all in the same port. What I want to happen is for the browser to search for a react route if an API one doesn't exist, like how you'd set up a react/node app with Webpack. Instead it just errors out.

Comment: I'm not having issues until I refresh the page anywhere that isn't specified in my urls.py files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then `views.html` renders the page that will run the app defined in `App.js`. And the problem you have is that if you go to a URL `http://yourserver/my-quiz`, where `my-quiz` is a quiz name, the request will be sent to the Django server, which says: 404, I don’t know about that URL.

One working solution is to add a catch-all route to your Django main app:

```
urlpatterns += re_path(r'.*', views.index)
```

as the last route. This simply makes Django render your app for each and every request, and react-router will take care of the routing.

The downside to this is that you won’t get a 404 if the page *really* doesn’t exist (in your case, there is no quiz by that name). I haven’t found a solution for that yet except duplicating routing configuration (in your case, checking in the Django app if a quiz with that name exists).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked. I didn't have to put the r in front of `".*'` but it's still working for now. Not sure if this is best practice but I like to handle error messages in the frontend side of things. If there's no quiz, there won't be anything from the GET request so just write some conditional logic where an error or "nothing's here" message gets displayed instead of the quiz.

Comment: Whoops, so this works but it created a separate issue. My GET requests aren't returning anything but an empty array. If I revert back to using `path('', views.index)` then it all works fine. What's weird is that when I test out the API routes in postman or the browser it all works fine, I'm just not getting anything through the frontend.

Comment: Figured out what's going on, the server is using the `'.*'` route first, despite me listing it last in my urls.py. So I'm actually getting my index.html from my GET requests, despite getting JSON data when I use Postman or the browser. Working on a fix.

Comment: you should handle unwanted url as 404 in reactjs router. check out https://reactrouter.com/web/example/no-match

Answer (score 0):

usually in the frontend framework like (angular, react, vue ) the routers only handle te calls in (the client side) and draw the correct component for each route so you need a component that works like a service, and there make calls to the backend api.  e.j.

utility.js

```
export function get_some_route(){
    return fetch('some_route');
}
```

the utility file contain functions to fetch the backend routes. so you can
import this file an get the data in the component rendered for the router.

your_component.js

```
import get_some_route from 'utility.js';
class x extends component{
  ...
  componentDidMount(){
     get_some_route().then(response => {
         // do some thing with the data e.j
         this.setState({data: response.data});
     }
  }
  ...
  render(){
      return(/*some html with the data */);
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not having issues fetching data, just when I refresh a route not specified in the urls.py files I included. For example, if I refresh "/api/quizzes" I get that JSON data, but if I refresh /name it'll error out since there's no /name route in my URLs and it doesn't know to use the React routes.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar issue but for me the django admin page was not showing. Adding this to my frontend/urls worked for me.

```
urlpatterns += re_path(r'^.*/$', views.index)
```